# How does Chrome know which tabs are playing sound?

Tags: google-chrome

How does chrome know which tabs are playing some sound? Alternatively, how does chrome know which tabs to put the speaker sign on?

Comment: Since Chrome is the one actually playing the music when the page requests it, adding a speaker symbol for the tabs that requested music to be played is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

This article may be useful:

From [ghacks.net](http://www.ghacks.net/2014/01/15/main-reason-chrome-tab-audio-indicators-firefox/):

"Google Chrome uses an internal version of Adobe Flash which Google can use to determine when Flash is being used for audio playback.

Mozilla does not have that luxury. While it is working on a patch to display indicators when HTML5 is being used for audio playback, it cannot do anything about plug-in contents on its own."

Assuming that's correct, then from there it's not hard to imagine that if they know of every single instance of flash being used for audio playback, that they probably have an associated property indicating which tab it is on.